# Estimate Probability distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution, sampling, chi-squared

I am planning an experiment to determine the frequency of a binary variable (valued 1 or 0).

Each day, there are 10,000 new events taking place

Each day, I get to draw 100 randomly out of the new 10,000 and see their outcome (either 1 or 0)

How do I estimate the frequency of 1 and 0 in the population with this data?

Is there a package in R that can fit a discrete probability distribution to this data?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for Maximum Likelihood estimation

Comment: Unless you have a LOT of days, there is little need to estimate the frequencies in this population. You can simply study all 10,000/day. It's a bit of an oddity for some to wrap their heads around, but when you have a population, there is no need to estimate any parameter of it. You have the parameter already. For example, on my laptop a <- sample.int(2, (10000*365*10), replace = TRUE)-1 generates 10 years of 0's and 1's in 4 sec and calculates the average (should be .5, of course) in .5 sec. "a" takes 278.5 Mb of storage.

Comment: In this case, I can't measure all 10,000 daily. We have limited capacity so can only actually measure 100 observations daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a population of size N=10,000 where 6,500 events occurred one day.

```
pop <- rep(c(0,1), times=c(3500, 6500))
table(pop)
#pop
#   0    1 
#3500 6500
```

Now suppose you can sample 100 of these (0,1) events *without replacement*.

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 10000
n <- 100
sam <- data.frame(id=1:n, event=sample(pop, size=n), prob=n/N)

table(sam$event)
# 0  1 
#30 70
```

So we got 70 out of 100. A maximum likelihood estimate of the total events in the population is simply 70/100 x 10,000 = 7,000. The standard error of this estimate is given by

```
sqrt((N-n)/N * N^2 * var(sam$event)/n)
#[1] 473.71
```

The 95% confidence interval is [6101 - 7898], which covers the true population total of 6,500. But 1 in 20 days you will likely get a bad sample.

R packages? Not really necessary for this experiment. For more complex sampling designs, I can only think of the **survey** package, but there may be others.

---

Now if you did this repeatedly, say for 10 days, you'd get an estimate for each day. An estimate of the total, according to a frequentist statistician, would be the total x N / n and an estimate for the SE calculated in a similar way. For example, suppose you found 3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8, 17, and 19 "positive" events from samples of 100 on ten consecutive days:

```
events1 <- c(3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8, 17, 19)
```

Which means "negative" or non-events occurring is:

```
events0 <- 100 - events1
```

A vector of (0,1) events can be constructed as follows using `rep`.

```
events <- rep(rep(c(0,1), each=10), times=c(events0, events1))
```

Let's define n and N as the number of events in your ten-day sample and in the ten-day population, respectively.

```
n <- 100 * 10
N <- 10000 * 10
```

The number of "positive" events in your ten-day sample is:

```
sum(events1)
#[1] 95
```

And the MLE in the ten-day population is:

```
(T <- sum(events1) * N / n)
[1] 9500
```

The standard error of this ten-day estimate is:

```
SE <- sqrt((N-n)/N * N^2 * var(events)/n); SE
[1] 923.0409
```

With 95% CI:

```
T + c(-1,1) * 1.96*SE
[1]  7690.84 11309.16
```

A Bayesian may say that each day should be re-estimated or updated based on the previous day's estimate, but I think the results would be fairly similar.

---

A Bayesian would use Bayes' Rule and use a Uniform(0,1) as a reasonable *prior* distribution for the proportion of "positive" events for the ten-day period. Unif(0,1) is the same as Beta(1,1). An experienced statistician (Frequentist or Bayesian) would recognise that the beta distribution is *conjugate* to the binomial distribution. Thus, the Bayesian would use the Beta(1+X, 1+N-X) distribution for the proportion of "positive" events over the ten-day period, where X is the total number of "positive" events (95) and N is the sample size (1000). Note that the mean of Beta(alpha, beta) = alpha/(alpha+beta).

In R:

```
n <- rep(100, 10)
events1 <- c(3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8, 17, 19)

X <- sum(events1)
N <- sum(n)

pmean = (1+X)/(2+N); pmean
#[1] 0.09580838

CI = qbeta(c(.025,.975), 1+X, 1+N-X); CI # 95% credible interval
#[1] 0.07837295 0.11477134
```

Thus, over the ten-day period, the proportion of positive events would be 9.58% of all events and there is a 95% probability that the true proportion lies between 7.84% and 11.48%. Extrapolating to the total population, we can say that 9.58% of 100,000 events or 9,581 events would be positive. This, as I said, is very similar to the frequentist approach.

**Meta-analysis**

Now, these two methods are effectively combining all ten days into one big sample, and estimating the proportion of positive events, or the total number of positive events, in the whole population. It may be more intuitive to combine the results of each day in a more appropriate way, based on weights, such as is done in a meta-analysis.

If p[k] is the estimated proportion on day k, and se[k] is its standard error, then the combined estimate is given by p_hat = sum(p[k] * w[k]) / sum(w[k]), where w[k] = (1 / se[k])^2, and the standard error is 1 / sqrt(sum(w[k]).

In R:

```
N <- rep(100000, 10) # Population and 10 day period
n <- rep(100, 10) 

events1 <- c(3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8, 17, 19)
events0 <- n - events1

p <- NULL; SE <- NULL; w <- NULL

for(k in seq_along(events1)){
  events <- c(rep(0, events0[k]), rep(1, events1[k]))
  p[k] <- sum(events1[k]) / n[k]
  SE[k] <- sqrt((N[k]-n[k]) / N[k] * var(events)/n[k])
  w[k] <- 1 / (SE[k])^2
}

p_hat <- sum(p*w)/sum(w); p_hat
#[1] 0.06997464

SE_p <- 1 / sqrt(sum(w)); SE_p
#[1] 0.007943816

(p_hat + c(-1,1) * 1.96 * SE_p)
#[1] 0.05440476 0.08554452
```

So about 7% of all events will be positive with 95% confidence interval (5.44% - 8.55%), which is not too different from the two crude methods used above. We get a smaller (and perhaps more accurate) estimate due to the skewed nature of the ten-day sample.

Comment: So let's suppose I have 10 samples, each of 100 each. What would the maximum likelihood of the total events in the population be? Let's suppose I collect values of (3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 8, 14, 8, 17, 19). Would I sum all values and look at their frequency? So, if the sum is 95 and each sample is 100, over ten days that is 1000. ((95/1000)*10,000*10) is the MLE of the total events in the population over the 10 days? How would I determine the SE and 95% CI for this estimate?

Comment: Yes - I think that sounds ok. See updated answer for calculation of SE and 95% CI. I'm wondering if correlated data would be an issue here though. As long as each day is independent of the next, then maybe there's no problem. But you didn't provide any context.

Comment: In this context, the observations can be assumed to be independent. Also is the variable “died” the same as T? 

SE <- sqrt((N-n)/N * N^2 * var(died)/n);

Comment: Would I describe the underlying distribution as a binomial distribution?

Comment: Sorry - `died` should be `events`. I've corrected that.

Comment: Each day the number of positive events is Binomially distributed with n=100 and p=p_hat (estimated from all ten days I would guess. For your data p_hat = 0.095).

Comment: Accepting this answer since this is the specific question I asked, but suppose I want to update the estimate every day, taking a bayesian appraoch as you mentioned, what different approach would i need to take?

Comment: Not sure about the Bayesian sequential technique. But I've given an overall method which was taught to me by Alex Cook at NUS. I've also provided a meta-analysis technique, which you may prefer.